# ACCESS/VBA: How to create a ON/OFF type switch to allow record modification on a form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was using a combobox on my search form to select whether to consult or modify a record.
To make it more user friendly (IMO), I put a togglebutton on a form, which controls the .AllowEdits property of my form. This way you can easily switch from reading to writing.

However I run into a problem; once .AllowEdits is switched to false, the togglebutton is not clickable
anymore !

What are my options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a command button instead. It will not get locked.
You will however run into similar problems with other controls like a combo box you would use for quick searching a record. If you have that problem, use the solution [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-56.html) to lock/unlock all your bound controls.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. I'll stick to using a command button, requires less code...

Comment: (as a note, add a me.refresh after changing the .allowedits to false, or it won't lock edits if an edit has been made)

Comment: I also have a OnCurrent sub that says If Me.AllowEdits Then Me.AllowEdits = False. And I also generally change the form header background color to clearly reflect the edit Status (orange background when in Edit mode, standard grey otherwise).

Comment: You can also change the caption of the command button to "Save Changes" or something similar when you are in edit mode. I have found that users generally like to have a save button even though it usually serves very little purpose on a standard bound MS Access form.